# how to update fields created dynamically using meteor

Tags: meteor

i have created a collection as below
and want to update field

lets say i want to update "field1" with type "checkbox"

here is my mongo collection data

```
"dynamicfields" : {
        "field1" : {
            "type" : "textarea"
        },
        "field2" : {
            "type" : "text"
        }
    }
```

is it possible? how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are look for the [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#up._S_rename) operator

Check syntaxis.

```
{$rename: { <field1>: <newName1>, <field2>: <newName2>, ... } }
```

Try with this.

```
Collection.update({_id:this._id},{$rename{'dynamicFields.field1':'dynamicFields.field111'}})
```

or

```
Collection.update({_id:this._id},{$rename{'dynamicFields:{'field1.type':'input'}}})
```

not tested code, but the `$rename` its what are you looking here, since you want to update the `field`

Comment: thanks,but field1 and field2 comes dynamically from code and want to update "field1" to "field111" and type = "textarea" , then what would be the update query.

Comment: yeah, but how would this query can identify that it should update or rename "field1" data to new one.

Comment: i don't get the question, the query will be look into `dynamicFields.field1:<newValue>` thats the query, you don't give to much code or a scenario to do this, you could pass new variables to the `<new value>` field for example

Comment: that's fine. but  if want to update "field1" to "field123"  then this query will not work.

Comment: Did you tested it? Please create a meteorpad and we can test the query you want if you want to upload the field just change to "dynamicFields":{field1:field2} for example

Comment: I ask about a meteorpad because on the question you are asking about update the "textarea" not the field "type" so if you want to update the field i gave you the answer, remember that mongo documents are objects so you can easy acces then with the .dot notation

Comment: yeah, that's fine. i got your answer but can not create meteorpad right now.